# Why JAXB does't marshal annotatied class instance when it is used as HashMap key?

Tags: json, xml, jaxb

In my restful API I use json-jackson to produce JSON output. So I have JAXB-annotatied class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Vertex")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "id", "label" })
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class RepresentedVertex implements Vertex
{
    private Vertex originalVertex;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public String getId()
    {
        return this.id().toString();
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "label")
    public String getLabel()
    {
        return this.label();
    }


    public RepresentedVertex(Vertex originalVertex)
    {
    super();
    this.originalVertex = originalVertex;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        buf.append("[").append(this.getId()).append("::").append(this.getLabel()).append("]");

        return buf.toString();
    }
```

When I return Response with entity = `List<RepresentedVertex>` all is OK - I get JSON out put with **id** and **label** values in accordance with annotated get-methods.

But when I return `Map<RepresentedVertex,List <RepresentedVertex>>` which contains RepresentedVertex as a key - I get output with result of `RepresentedVertex.toSting()` method (i.e. [1245311::testLabel]) for Map key like that:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "message": "Ok complete",
    "content": {
        "[1245311::testLabel]": [
            {
                "id": "163852352",
                "label": "dataset"
            },
            {
                "id": "163864664",
                "label": "dataset"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

... but I want separate **id** and **label** values like that:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "message": "Ok complete",
    "content": {
        "vertex": { "id": "1245311",  "label": "testLabel"}: [
            {
                "id": "163852352",
                "label": "dataset"
            },
            {
                "id": "163864664",
                "label": "dataset"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What wrong with jaxb-representation of Map key in this case?

Comment: your question is not clear,  `[1245311::testLabel]` is obvious as your are overriding `toString`

Comment: I have added some clarification

Comment: Just to let you know.. what you are expecting isn't a correct JSON and can't be done. You can validate your JSON here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Ooh.. Thanks. It seems that  there is only one way to serialise Map key object to JSON - calling .toString() method

Answer (score 0):

... so, as noted in the comments what I expecting isn't a correct JSON. 
So I made JAXB annotaited wrapper-class for Map and get output as follows:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "message": "Ok complete",
    "content": {
        "pairs": [{
            "vertex": {
                "id": "1245311",
                "label": "testLabel"
            },
            "objects": [{
                    "id": "163852352",
                    "label": "dataset"
                },
                {
                    "id": "163864664",
                    "label": "dataset"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```